# Shortcut to comment code on codesandbox.io

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard, shortcut, codesandbox

I'm learning React on codesandbox.io which it's exactly like VSCode, my main code editor currently.

However I'm not able to find the shortcut to comment and uncomment lines of code and this is very frustrating for me.

The keyboard shortcut to comment code in VSCode is **CMD + Shift + 7** (in a Spanish keyboard) but it doesn't work in codesandbox.io. I think the shortcut in English keyboards is just **CMD + /**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select the code you want to comment out then press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

To remove the comment, press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>.

Comment: You can use  CMD+k then CMD+c for both commenting and uncommenting

Answer (score 1):

Try with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, it worked for me. I am using Linux - Elementary OS 0.5.

For example: [image]

Answer (score 0):

On CodeSandbox using macOS:

- To toggle block comment, press <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
- To toggle line comment, press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem and for me this works fine.

**To comment a line:** <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

**To uncomment a line:** <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. According to [@Julien Aubert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65673057/3025856), it is `CMD`, not `CTRL`. Are you certain this is correct? If so, does `CTRL` _also_ work?

Answer (score -1):

On **Windows** it's:

```
CTRL + /
```

Make sure that "/" is the one next to SHIFT button.